# How to test with lower android versions using android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there any way to configure emulator to work with lower android versions? It's taking 4.2.2 as default version, even while creating a new emulator it doesn't show any other versions.

Comment: Run your sdk manager and check lower version are installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need download low version SDK with ADT tool(Android SDK Manager), so that you can create the simulator with low version.

Answer (score 1):

Open the SDK Manager and download the version(s) of the SDK you want to use. After you have done that they will be available in the drop down when you setup a new emulator.

Answer (score 0):

add this in you android manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

### its run in API 8 to API 17. Hope you have created emulator so all version.

Comment: you have downloaded all OS version in your SDK?? if not then update your SDK first..